# Get exposed port from within docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, uwsgi

I have a docker-compose.yml file as follows:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8086"
    environment:
      - PORT=8086
```

a dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv

COPY Pipfile* /app/

RUN cd /app &&  pipenv lock --keep-outdated --requirements > requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY . /app/src

WORKDIR /app/src

EXPOSE ${PORT}

CMD uwsgi --http :${PORT} --wsgi-file server.py --callable main
```

So basically, I am running a server on a given port, which I expose in my Dockerfile and docker-compose. However, when I run two instances of these containers, I need a way for them to each use their own port. I also cannot hardcode values as I need to be able to scale to n instances. So rather than using the environment variable `PORT`, I need to somehow get each port from within the running container, expose it, and run the server on that port.

When I call `docker-compose up --scale server=2` to run two server containers, I am unable to send HTTP requests because the port mappings do not match up.

Essentially what I am trying to do is have each container run uwsgi using the port allocated to it by docker-compose. Is there any way to achieve this in a nice manner?

Example:
[image]

Source: https://github.com/distribworks/dkron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `HOST_PORT` part in your `server` service definition. A service's port definition should be `HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT` as per https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/. Otherwise a random `HOST_PORT` will be chosen.

You can clone a working sample environment [here](https://github.com/jdsalaro/snippets/blob/main/docker/65896179-get-exposed-port-from-within-docker-compose/) or see it working [here](https://github.com/jdsalaro/snippets/blob/main/docker/65896179-get-exposed-port-from-within-docker-compose/DOCS.ipynb).

You can always see which port Docker Compose is choosing by issuing:

```
jdsalaro$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                         COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                     NAMES
de0120c61c1e   65896179-get-exposed-port-from-within-docker-compose_server   "/bin/sh -c 'uwsgi -…"   12 seconds ago   Up 11 seconds   0.0.0.0:49157->8086/tcp   65896179-get-exposed-port-from-within-docker-compose_server_1
```

To fix your problem, just provide a `HOST_PORT` as mentioned:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
    environment:
      - PORT=8086
```

---

When using `--scale`, for example `--scale server=4`, one can provide a range of ports as `HOST_PORT` instead as follows:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000-8004:8086"
    environment:
      - PORT=8086
```

Comment: (The two port numbers don't need to match, and it's okay to pick a fixed container-side port number and remap it via `ports:`.  That will simplify your image setup.)

Comment: Hmm, when I try this, I get the error: `Bind for 0.0.0.0:8086 failed: port is already allocated` when I run `docker-compose up --scale server=2`

Comment: ^ I believe that is my fundamental problem: I need to be able to run two (or more) servers using `docker-compose up --scale server=n` without their ports conflicting. I know this can be done (somehow) given I've seen an example implementation (but using go instead of python/uwsgi -- I added picture above)

Comment: Regarding the `Bind for 0.0.0.0:8086 failed: port is already allocated` error, that's expected as port `8086` has already been allocated by the first instance in `--scale server=2` and there's no port `8086` left for the second instance left.

Comment: As to `I need to be able to run two (or more) servers`, that's also possible, I should have added that portion to my answer. When `--scale` is used you can use a range of ports as a `HOST_PORT` in the service definition, for example `8000-8004:8086`. I've updated my answer and [the example project accordingly](https://github.com/jdsalaro/snippets/blob/main/docker/65896179-get-exposed-port-from-within-docker-compose/DOCS.ipynb).

Comment: Think you, this is what I was looking for. I had one last question: is there any way to get the port docker eventually chooses (from docker ps) from within a single server? For example, if I want the servers to be able to communicate with each other, how do I get their network locations once docker spins up the containers?

Comment: @mlz7, glad that helped, mark the question as answered so it doesn't come up in others' feeds as unanswered. As for your question, yes, it's possible and even easier. `docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Status}}\t{{.Names}}"` will show you the names  of the containers `docker-compose` just spun up. You can then use that name from within the container to reach other containers, for example `docker exec -it hello_server_1 ping hello_server_2` will `ping` `hello_server_2` from `hello_server_1`. Those names will be resolved to the proper IPs.

Comment: Ah thank you so much! Marking as answered